# DGGS projections with PostGIS or pgLatLon

Tags: postgresql, dggs, pglatlon

Important DGGS projections (like ISEA4T, ISEA4D or ISEA7H variants of [ISEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snyder_equal-area_projection)) are free at https://github.com/sahrk/DGGRID , the [**DGGRID Software Project**](https://www.discreteglobalgrids.org/software/),
but I not see how to use it with PostGIS. Only maybe drawing and exporting each hierarchical level of the (big data) grid.

Ideal is a function pair like [*ST_GeoHash*](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeoHash.html) / [*ST_GeomFromGeoHash*](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoHash.html) that **encode/decode cell identifiers of the grid**.

**Some clue or workaround to "plug" DGGRID into PostgreSQL?** It can be a plug  for [PostGIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS) or [pgLatLon](https://www.public-software-group.org/pgLatLon) extensions.

---

NOTES FOR CURIOUS READERS:

- *Discrete Global Grid Systems* (DGGS) are the trend in GIS, and since 2017 has an [standard  OGC Abstract Specification](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/as/15-104r5/15-104r5.html).
- `pgLatLon` extension is a lightweight alternative for PostGIS, see  https://www.public-software-group.org/pgLatLon
- DGGRID (and ISEA4T, ISEA4D, ISEA7H grids) documentation is at [git/sahrk/DGGRID/dggridManualV71.pdf](https://github.com/sahrk/DGGRID/raw/8b1ae8e37a5271c4c79e2d3e3ff6c9ce15ef34e3/dggridManualV71.pdf). About first levels of the grid, they are analog to ISEA3H, [described here](http://webpages.sou.edu/%7Esahrk/dgg/images/foldups/icosapics1.html) with general [conventions for orientation here](https://www.discreteglobalgrids.org/dgg-orientation/).  See also [DGGRID use case examples](https://www.discreteglobalgrids.org/dggrid-users/).

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS use *PROJ.org*, and recent PROJ versions has implemented some projections, used in DGGS candidates:

- PROJ **v8.2+** added [S2 Geometry's projection](https://proj.org/operations/projections/s2.html).
- PROJ **v??+** added [QSC projection](https://proj.org/operations/projections/qsc.html).
- PROJ **v??+** added partial [ISEA](https://proj.org/operations/projections/isea.html), [without inverse](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/423014/7505).
- PROJ **v4.8+** added [rHEALPix](https://proj.org/operations/projections/rhealpix.html). See [urn:doi:10.1088/1755-1315/34/1/012012](http://doi.org/10.1088/1755-1315/34/1/012012) for "rHEALPix is DGGS" demonstration.
- ...

You can check your PostGIS's PROJ version by `SELECT postgis_full_version()`.

Comment: How does one use these from within Postgres?