# How to see ISEA with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Using the spatial reference [`+proj=isea`](https://proj.org/operations/projections/isea.html) and comparing with others, in separate tables to avoid confusion in the QGIS renderization. But **no visualization**... is a QGIS bug? For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1_b AS    -- Pure WGS84
  SELECT 1 AS gid,
         ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6b'), 4326) AS geom
;
CREATE TABLE test1_c AS    -- Same but Shere instead ellipsoid
  SELECT 1 AS gid,
       ST_Transform(
          ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6c'),4326),
          '+proj=lonlat +ellps=sphere'
       ) AS geom
;
CREATE TABLE test1_f AS   -- ISEA, that is also Shere
  SELECT 1 AS gid, 
        ST_Transform(
           ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6f'),4326),
           '+proj=isea'
        ) AS geom
;
```

QGIS v3 only shows `test1_b` and `test1_c`:

[image]

---

### Notes

- [Geohashes](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html) `d2g6b`, `d2g6c` and `d2g6f` are horizontal neighbors. As [showed before](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419567/7505), the ISEA projection use `ellps=sphere`, and as showed by illustration (`d2g6c` box), QGIS can plot `ellps=sphere`... I supposed that QGIS can plot  `d2g6c` also, using similar infrastructure.
- Supposing that `d2g6f` is a small box contained into an *ISEA's icosahedron face*... So, no risc of "coordinate jump".
- In the related questions,  "[How to use ISEA projection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/418623/7505)" and "[DGGS projections with PostGIS or pgLatLon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/360318/7505)", no clues about visualization.
- Double transform also not works, is not valid to transform ISEA back to any simple SRID.
- Dump to text seems good: `select st_astext(geom) from test1_f` results the WKT below

```
 POLYGON((
  -9457665.085273389 722136.153457215,
  -9460296.69550779  726590.233366592,
  -9456290.810885958 728872.6605645764,
  -9453658.792895738 724419.0107246666,
  -9457665.085273389 722136.153457215
))
```

---

(edit)

### Seems that "*no inverse* **→** *no visualization*"

As [Even Rouault commented here](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/3047#issuecomment-1036177852),

> the reason is much likely that only the forward method 
> (geographic coordinates → projected coordinates) is implemented, 
> whereas QGIS also requires the inverse method to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is only a missing parameter, needed to tell PostGIS that you want it to use use a sphererical projection.

In your SQL, please try using:

```
'+proj=isea +ellps=sphere'
```

instead of the mere

```
'+proj=isea'
```

that is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1_f AS   -- ISEA, that is also Shere
  SELECT 1 AS gid, 
        ST_Transform(
           ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6f'),4326),
           '+proj=isea +ellps=sphere'
        ) AS geom
;
```

Comment: Hi, it is not working for QGIS, no image... Can you post an evidence image?

Comment: Do you have the chance to share the input dataset? or at least of a dataset of the same type, which is not working as expected?

Comment: Hi @RafDouglas, can you see it on the screen? Can you see your `test1_f` table? If you see, use the "print screen" key of your computer to copy/paste your evidence image here at your answer.   Seems that you not see (!), or not see in the correct place... Check my new note at the end of the [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/423014/7505#question), *"no inverse → no visualization"*.