# How to see rHEALPix with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Using the spatial reference [`+proj=rhealpix`](https://proj.org/operations/projections/rhealpix.html) and comparing with "pure WGS84", in separate tables to avoid confusion in the QGIS renderization. But **no visualization**... is a QGIS bug? For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1_b AS    -- Pure WGS84
  SELECT 1 AS gid,
         ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6b'), 4326) AS geom
;

CREATE TABLE test1_c AS   -- rHEALPix to WGS84 (double transform)
  SELECT 1 AS gid, 
      ST_Transform(
        ST_Transform(
           ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6c'),4326),
           '+proj=rhealpix +ellps=WGS84 +south_square=0 +north_square=2'
        ),
        4326
      ) AS geom
; -- BUG!?  ERROR:  ST_Transform: Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID

CREATE TABLE test1_f AS   -- rHEALPix
  SELECT 1 AS gid, 
        ST_Transform(
           ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6f'),4326),
           '+proj=rhealpix +ellps=WGS84 +south_square=0 +north_square=2'
        ) AS geom
;
```

QGIS v3 only shows `test1_b`:

[image]

---

### Notes

- [Geohashes](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html) `d2g6b`, `d2g6c` and `d2g6f` are small boxes and  horizontal neighbors.
- In a related question,  "[How to see ISEA with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/423014/7505)", no clues about visualization, except that rHEALPix is fine because has inverse — as [Proj guide](https://proj.org/operations/projections/rhealpix.html)  say about available forms, *"Forward and inverse, spherical and ellipsoidal"*.
- Double transform also not works.
- Dump to text seems good: `select st_astext(geom) from test1_f` results the WKT below

```
 POLYGON((
  -8238641.204453768 612551.682534819,
  -8238641.204453768 618263.7731066671,
  -8233754.703146263 618263.7731066671,
  -8233754.703146263 612551.682534819,
  -8238641.204453768 612551.682534819
))
```

- Using WGS84 as option after alert,

[image]

Comment: Is it an "[old-PROJ problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/424112/7505)"?

Answer (score 2):

### The PostGIS inverse only works for registered transform

The PostGIS error, *"ST_Transform: Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID"* is sayng that we must to INSERT the projection in the `spatial_ref_sys` table. A new and non-standard projection must use the "free range" of the srid column, you can use any  arbitrary integer after `SELECT MAX(srid) FROM spatial_ref_sys`  of the PostGIS standard installation, is 104992. So we can use 955001.

```sql
INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text) VALUES
(
  955001, -- arbitrary number after 105000
  'DGGS:rHEALPix', -- arbitrary label
  9000,   -- arbitrary number
  '+proj=rhealpix +ellps=WGS84 +south_square=0 +north_square=2'
);
```

### Repeat with SRID instead string

And not need one table per projection, QGIS manages the projection diversity. Here adding a `name` for each.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test2 AS
    SELECT 1 AS gid, 'WGS84' as name,
           ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6b'), 4326) AS geom

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'back',
      ST_Transform(    -- PostGIS inversion
        ST_Transform(
           ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6c'),4326),
           955001 -- rhealpix
        ),
        4326      -- back to "pure WGS84" (PostGIS invertion) 
      )

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 3 AS gid, 'rHEALPix', 
        ST_Transform(
           ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoHash('d2g6f'),4326),
           955001 -- rhealpix
        )
;
```

### Result on QGIS

[image]

### Discussion and conclusion

QGIS say nothing, but the PostGIS error was a good clue. QGIS need to use the *inverse transform*  to show the geometry, and **it only works for registered SRIDs**.