# Safe upgrade of PROJ for PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, proj, upgrade, dggs

Is there a safe way to install fresh [PROJ](https://proj.org/install.html), for example v8.2, in a Debian Linux server, for use with (for example) PostGIS v3?

The installation of PROJ was implicit in the PostGIS's, I never do directly... And it seems that PostGIS must be prepared for a major PROJ's version upgrade (7.x to 8.x).

RATIONALE: I'm looking for [modern DGGS projections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/424099/7505), so I need modern PROJ. Even using POSTGIS v3.2, the PROJ version is 7, but [`s2` projection](https://proj.org/operations/projections/s2.html) for example needs PROJ v8.2+. Other questions, [like this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/424025/7505), shows a bug that perhaps is an "old-PROJ problem".

Comment: I would say you will probably find issues during/after the upgrading process. If I were you I will do a fresh installation of the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks @Gery, make sense... But remember that [PostGIS  v3.2.x](http://planet.postgis.net/) is the fresher (!).

Comment: You are right, you are using the powerful sudo thing right? If so, everything comes together (proj7+postgis3.2), unless you add a gis-like dev repository (eg. unstable gis, if I am right) and install first proj8 (you can find which version to be installed) and then do the pgsql-postgis steps, or you can install painfully everything from source =) Beste Grüße!